# Is it possible to fully install ubuntu instead of dual booting it with windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

After i dual booted Ubuntu on my laptop i noticed things haven't been right on my windows 7 OS and some programs that i'm trying to download on my ubuntu os is not working because of the other OS files interfering after the hard drive.besides the fact i want to know if there is a way to instead of dual booting linux to somehow bring back up the installation and do a full install of ubuntu instead of just dual booting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It's very easy. You can just run the Ubuntu CD/ USB and choose **Install Ubuntu** from the desktop. Use the install option that says: **"Guided: Use entire disk"**

Keep in mind that this will overwrite **everything**. If there are things you need to keep, there is a more complicated option to grow your Linux partitions, but I have had bad luck growing them to the left. If you want more info on growing/ moving/ resizing partitions, here are some other resources:

[How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)
http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

I will add that if you would prefer to keep Windows 7 installed and just get things working better, that's always (well usually) an option. I along with the rest of askubuntu.com are more than willing to help however possible. I haven't personally had any issues with one OS affecting another; could you possibly have tried to run, for example, a **.exe** (Windows executive) file on Linux, or some Linux command(s) in the Windows CLI? Just some thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

As was stated earlier, growing partition can always be a risk, if you want to do this I personally recommend a full new install, especially for a novice computer user.

If you absolutely need windows programs to run and you can't get them running using wine, I would suggest to you to use virtual box and create a virtual windows 7 (or 8 or 10 for that matter) to run those programs. Take note that this does not work perfectly for high end games sinse virtual box uses its own video driver.

Some more info on:
Wine: https://www.winehq.org/
Virtual box: https://www.virtualbox.org/

Read the info on these two pages to get an idea of what you'll be getting yourself into and then deside what is best for your situation.

Good luck.